# Java Spring password encoding fail

Tags: java, spring-security

I don't know why my `UserEntity.java` fail to encode the password when I test it in debug mode. The password appear without MD5 encoded. Else is when I click on `org.springframework.security.authentication` it's say:

> this element has no attached Javadoc and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached source

I have `springframework-core` in Maven dependencies which contain the both classes of `Md5PasswordEncoder.java` and `PasswordEncoder.java`.
If this two needs a bean definition how do I create it?

```java
package com.example.j2eeapp.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder;

/**
 * Entity to hold application user data - first name, last name, etc.
 */
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9014169812363387062L;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String userName;
    private String password;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        PasswordEncoder crypto = new Md5PasswordEncoder();
        this.password = crypto.encodePassword(password, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not use the MD5 algorithm.

Comment: Then what to use? I try to make it working.

Comment: try to edit PasswordEncoder to Md5PasswordEncoder , do you use web.xml

Comment: I did how you say but is not working. What i must to write in web.xml?